# how to create an empty project folder (fragment plug-in type) on eclipse programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, wizard

I need to create an empty folder while using a **postPerformFinish** function activated after the finish button from a wizard, but I need it to be considered as an **empty project** (fragment plug-in type).

I have tried one simple way that I have found on internet to create folder but it seems like I have done some mistake.

Below is the code :

```
File fragmentProject = new File(ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getLocation()+DataModelFacetCreationWizardPageFragment.fragmentProjectName); 

try {
    fragmentProject.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is not a simple task. A fragment plug-in needs at least a .project file and a MANIFEST.MF specifying the host plug-in. I suggest you study `org.eclipse.pde.internal.ui.wizards.plugin.NewFragmentProjectWizard` and the various helper classes it uses.

Comment: As note that you never use `File` to create things in an Eclipse workspace. Use `IFile`, `IFolder`, `IProject`.

Comment: IProject worked perfectly